# Problem in installing cantera 2.0.0

Tags: 14.04

I have a problem in installing cantera library as the instructions described here:
https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Extend-bazaar/solvers/combustion/flameletFoam#Cantera_Source

there is a problem that the solution is mentioned but I don't know how should I solve it:
cannot find -lctlapack or cannot find -lctblas -> reinstall Cantera 2.0.0 adding the option single_library=yes

How should I add the option single_library=yes?!

Comment: At a guess, go back to the `scons build optimize=n blas_lapack_libs=blas,lapack prefix=/opt/cantera python_package=none` step and add `single_library=yes` to the command line

Comment: Thanks,yes it was like that. Now in the next step, could you please tell me how should I set an environment as mentioned here?: https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Extend-bazaar/solvers/combustion/flameletFoam#OpenFOAM_Source